# How to draw double stranded crossing using XYpic

Tags: xy-pic

[image: Double stranded crossing]

I want to draw this double stranded crossing of a knot with `xypic`. How do I do this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the needed code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
&\ar@{-}[ddd]|!{[d]}\hole|!{[dd]}\hole &\ar@{-}[ddd]|!{[d]}\hole|!{[dd]}\hole\\
\ar@{-}[rrr]&&&\\
\ar@{-}[rrr]&&&\\
&&\\
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
&&\ar@{-}[ddddd]|!{[dd]}\hole|!{[ddd]}\hole &\ar@{-}[ddddd]|!{[dd]}\hole|!{[ddd]}\hole\\
\\
\ar@{-}[rrrrr]&&&&&\\
\ar@{-}[rrrrr]&&&&&\\
\\
&&&\\
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: \@karlkoeller: How do I resize this? I want to fit this inside two angle braces. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeus Please ask a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Or with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,every arrow/.append style={dash}
    ,row sep={1cm,between origins}
    ,column sep={1cm,between origins}]
& \arrow{ddd} & \arrow{ddd} & \\
\arrow[crossing over]{rrr}& & &\null \\
\arrow[crossing over]{rrr}& & &\null \\
& \null & \null &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Of course, this is highly adjustable:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,every arrow/.append style={dash}
    ,row sep={1cm,between origins}
    ,column sep={1cm,between origins}]
&[1cm] \arrow{ddd} & \arrow{ddd} &[1cm] \\[1cm]
\arrow[crossing over]{rrr}& & &\null \\
\arrow[crossing over]{rrr}& & &\null \\[1cm]
& \null & \null &
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zeus You are very welcome.